# How can I install/remove ceiling lights from the attic?

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture, attic, safety

I have a home with vaulted ceilings (20 ft high) and recessed lighting. I have access to the fixtures and wiring from a stand-up attic. I have needed to rent a very high ladder or scaffolding to change bulbs.

Are fixtures available that can be lifted from the attic to replace bulbs?  I'm concerned about the safety of heights - especially one that currently needs replacing that lights the front stoop.  The steps add another 5-6 feet to the drop to a concrete sidewalk or bricked steps!

I've googled several terms and phrases to no avail.  Also, the floor help at Lowes/Home Depot have no suggestions.

If appropriate fixtures are available I will rent scaffolding and do a one-time weekend project to install fixtures that can be lifted from the attic.

Comment: I believe there are commercial fixtures that fit your need. I am looking for the same. Have you found those fixtures?

Answer (score 3):

The real practical solution to this issue is to acquire a long reach light bulb changing pole. These come in a variety of styles and extendable lengths. The particular type of bulbs that you intend to replace will determine the type of pole that you select.

It is always safer to be standing on solid ground with an extension pole than to try to balance on the top of a ladder. And if you follow my suggestion there will be no need to enter your attic and be changing out any fixtures.

Google Images with the phrase "**long reach light bulb changer**"  will show you all the options rather than me posting a plethora of pictures here.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the changing poles that you describe.  From the ground, this would require a pole of 15' or so which is unwieldy and I don't know if my aim and unsteady hand will work - even if I found such a pole.  Also, in some cases I would need to remove a bezel or lens to get to the actual light.  Is there any such thing as a light fixture that can be installed and removed from the attic??